# Streaming video data from html page

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, html5-video

I am trying to send video data from an html page which uses the computers webcam. I am wondering how to get this video data and send it to my server.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

The first is to use WebRTC, with a server as a "peer".  This requires you to set up a server that will work in this mode, and then do something with the video.  It is complicated.  Codecs are automatically negotiated.  Bitrate can change to match current network conditions.  There is NAT traversal (which shouldn't be a problem since your server will always have the ability to open ports on itself).

Once you get the signalling figured out, take a look at gstreamer's WebRTC implementation.  It's still one of the easiest ways to get server-side video.  (At least, until the node-webrtc package implements it!  Coming soon!!)

The second method is to use the MediaRecorder API to encode that MediaStream from the camera and send the resulting data to a server over binary Web Socket.  This is significantly simpler, but doesn't allow for automatically adjusting the bandwidth mid-stream.

I wrote up some example code for Facebook awhile back, for streaming from a canvas.  Your use case is actually simpler, as you don't need to capture the canvas... you already have a MediaStream.  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example